# NullPointerException on GoogleMaps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

Updating to API 19 was really annoying. I really had a hard time figuring out on how to deal with the google play services. However, when I run it, this error shows to me.

```
11-11 04:25:27.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.synergy88studios.quezoncityguide/com.synergy88studios.quezoncityguide.QuezonCityMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The logcat points to this line in my class:

```
      map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
```

I don't know what is probably wrong here.

Here is my class:

```
public class QuezonCityMap extends FragmentActivity {

final Context context = this;
Button routes;
double latitude = 14.635576;
double longitude = 121.033115;
LatLng latlng = new LatLng(14.6353475, 121.0327501);
LatLngBounds QC = new LatLngBounds(
          new LatLng(14.656669, 120.998598), new LatLng(14.666965, 121.098934));
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Shell").snippet("Sa tabi ng Estuar Building");
Marker mark;
GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
TextView tvDistanceDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quezon_city_map);
           tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);
       // Initializing
       markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

       // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
       SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

       // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
       map = fm.getMap();

       // Set Compass Enabled

       map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
       map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

       // create marker
       // Changing marker icon
       marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.share));
       map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));

       // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
       map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

       mark = map.addMarker(marker);

       //button
      map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {

                // adding marker

                if(arg0.zoom <16){
                   mark.setVisible(false);}
                else
                    mark.setVisible(true);

                if(arg0.zoom > 17){
                    mark.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.share));
                }
            }
        });

       // Setting onclick event listener for the map
       map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

               // Already two locations
               if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                   markerPoints.clear();
                   map.clear();

                   MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Shell").snippet("Sa tabi ng Estuar Building");

                   // Changing marker icon
                   marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.share));

                   // adding marker
                  map.addMarker(marker);
               }

               // Adding new item to the ArrayList
               markerPoints.add(point);

               // Creating MarkerOptions
               MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

               // Setting the position of the marker
               options.position(point);

               /**
               * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
               * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
               */
               if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                   options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
               }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                   options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
               }

               // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
               map.addMarker(options);

               // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
               if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                   LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                   LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                   // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                   String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                   DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                   // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                   downloadTask.execute(url);
               }
           }
       });
   }

   private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

       // Origin of route
       String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

       // Destination of route
       String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

       // Sensor enabled
       String sensor = "sensor=false";

       // Building the parameters to the web service
       String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

       // Output format
       String output = "json";

       // Building the url to the web service
       String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

       return url;
   }

   /** A method to download json data from url */
   private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
       String data = "";
       InputStream iStream = null;
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
       try{
           URL url = new URL(strUrl);

           // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           // Connecting to url
           urlConnection.connect();

           // Reading data from url
           iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

           StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

           String line = "";
           while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
               sb.append(line);
           }

           data = sb.toString();

           br.close();

       }catch(Exception e){
           Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
       }finally{
           iStream.close();
           urlConnection.disconnect();
       }
       return data;
   }

   // Fetches data from url passed
   private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

       // Downloading data in non-ui thread
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

           // For storing data from web service
           String data = "";

           try{
               // Fetching the data from web service
               data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
           }catch(Exception e){
               Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
           }
           return data;
       }

       // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
       // doInBackground()
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

           // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
           parserTask.execute(result);
       }
   }

   /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
   private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

       // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
       @Override
       protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

           JSONObject jObject;
           List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

           try{
               jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
               DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

               // Starts parsing data
               routes = parser.parse(jObject);
           }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return routes;
       }

       // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
           ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
           PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
           MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
           String distance = "";
           String duration = "";

           if(result.size()<1){
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return;
           }

           // Traversing through all the routes
           for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
               points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
               lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

               // Fetching i-th route
               List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

               // Fetching all the points in i-th route
               for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                   HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                   if(j==0){    // Get distance from the list
                       distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                       continue;
                   }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                       duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                       continue;
                   }

                   double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                   double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                   LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                   points.add(position);
               }

               // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
               lineOptions.addAll(points);
               lineOptions.width(2);
               lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
           }

           tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

           // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
           map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
       }
}
```

I can't find what could be null here. There is no error in the class. Can please someone help me? Thanks. Here is my logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.synergy88studios.quezoncityguide/com.synergy88studios.quezoncityguide.QuezonCityMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.synergy88studios.quezoncityguide.QuezonCityMap.onCreate(QuezonCityMap.java:83)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    ... 11 more
```

**My XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".QuezonCityMap" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonRoutes"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
     />
```

Comment: what is line 83 `QuezonCityMap.java`?

Comment: `map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);`

Comment: map is null. check it. `fm` is probably null

Comment: post your xml. check using a simple `if(map==null)`

Comment: remove this `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` coz you also have `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: i tried to add these lines `if(map==null){map = fm.getMap();}` and this ` if(map!=null){map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);} ` still nullpointerexception

Comment: and do check this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html. check the availability of google play services before initializing map and try. map is null and checking for null is true and then you initialize so get NPE.

Comment: suddenly my previous map app doesn't run anymore. damn google play services. :(

Comment: What is the version of Google Play Services app on your device?

Comment: I ran the app on my S4, map is not being displayed, LocationFinder Button and Zoom Buttons are there. :(

Comment: I updated google play services :(

Comment: It's working now. damn update.